# jq test function for Boolean NOT

Tags: json, parsing, jq

New to jq, trying to solve this parsing problem:
I need to find all users that are NOT in the @xyz.com domain. Using this:

```
jq '.[] | select(.email | test("@xyz.com")) | {id, username}
```

which shows all users IN the domain, great.
Tried various "NOT" ways, with no success, like so:

```
jq '.[] | select(.email | test("@xyz.com"; !=)) | {id, username} 
jq '.[] | select(.email | != test("@xyz.com"; "!=")) | {id, username}
```

which does not work (syntax errors).....
How/where do I place the NOT in jq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`not` should negate the boolean value used by `select`, so it has to be a part of its argument (i.e. go inside of it):

```bash
jq '.[] | select(.email | test("@xyz.com") | not) | {id, username}'
```

Note: For a simple substring match you can also use `contains` instead of `test`, which is used for full regex matches.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2158479/pmf Thanks, did not think of using a lowercase "not"...

Comment: @TomS You can find it here: [https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#and%2For%2Fnot](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#and%2For%2Fnot).

Comment: So conatins doesn't work (but test does).

Comment: @TomS Try spelling it `contains`.

Comment: I tried filtering for two conditions ```jq '.[] | select(.email | test("@xyz.com") | not | test("@abc.com") | not) | {id, username, email}'```, but get syntax error: jq: error (at <stdin>:18697): boolean (true) cannot be matched, as it is not a string
exit status 5

Comment: @TomS Of course you do. `not` produces a boolean which you cannot string-match anymore. Instead, construct your full positive condition, and negate its result (e.g. `test("…") and test("…") | not`, although you could probably combine those two `test`s into one…).

Comment: I did.. just not here. does not work. using jqplay, it recognizes `contain` (blue cmd ok, not to run), but not `contains`
`jq '.[] | select(.email | contains("@axs.tv") | {id, username, email}'` yields `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ';' or ')' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.[] | select(.email | contains("@axs.tv") | {id, username, email}                                                                
jq: 1 compile error
exit status 3`

Comment: @TomS `contains("@axs.tv")` is correct but you forgot to close `select`'s paren: `jq '.[] | select(.email | contains("@axs.tv")) | {id, username, email}'` should do the job.

Comment: OK, need to learn all this at a deeper level. thanks for your help. back to school at a later time